# Transition animation on v-if

Tags: vue.js, css-transitions, transition

I have an overlay card which by only shows if `foo == true`.

In my recent projects, I've used `vuetify` transition. but this time I am not using vuetify.

Is there any way to achieve this with pure css or javascript?

Answer (score 2):

[Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Single-Elements-Components) are your friend:

```html
<div id="demo">
  <button v-on:click="show = !show">
    Toggle
    </button>
  <transition name="fade">
    <p v-if="show">hello</p>
  </transition>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    show: true
  }
})
```

```css
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes this works too. But in my case, instead of assigning the `v-if` to a normal HTML element, I have a vue component. and it didn't work